# I want to implement a remember me functionality in my android code but I am not sure where to start

Tags: java, android, session, checkbox, remember-me

I want to implement a remember me functionality in my android code but I'm not sure where to start because my code is type of complex. I'm not sure where to put things so please help me

I want to make phone no and password remember only when login is true so please help me. This is my codes and please tell me where to put your suggestions in my code it will be better if you edit it thank you

this is login code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



import static example.R.layout.login;

public class login extends Activity {

TextView signup_text;
Button login_button;
EditText PHONE_NO, PASSWORD;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    signup_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    signup_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(login.this, register.class));
        }
    });
    PHONE_NO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
    PASSWORD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);


    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String phone_no = PHONE_NO.getText().toString();
            String password = PASSWORD.getText().toString();


            if (phone_no.equals("") || password.equals("")) {

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
                builder.setTitle("Something went wrong...");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill all the fields...");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            } else {

                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(login.this);
                backgroundTask.execute("login", phone_no, password);

            }


        }
    });


}
}
```

and this is `backgroundtask.java`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;

 import android.widget.CheckBox;
  import android.widget.EditText;


 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  import com.google.gson.*;


 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.ProtocolException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.net.URLEncoder;



public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
String register_url = "http://10.0.0.4/loginapp/register.php";
String login_url = "http://10.0.0.4/loginapp/login.php";



Context ctx;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Activity activity;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;


public BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {

    this.ctx = ctx;
    activity = (Activity) ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to server .... ");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(register_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String owner_name = params[1];
            String shop_name = params[2];
            String phone_no = params[3];
            String shop_address = params[4];
            String opening_time = params[5];
            String closing_time = params[6];
            String password = params[7];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("owner_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(owner_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("shop_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(shop_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("phone_no", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone_no, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("shop_address", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(shop_address, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("opening_time", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(opening_time, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("closing_time", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(closing_time, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {


                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } else if (method.equals("login")) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String phone_no, password;
            phone_no = params[1];
            password = params[2];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("phone_no", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone_no, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {


                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

    progressDialog.dismiss();
    try {


        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonarry = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        JSONObject JO = jsonarry.getJSONObject(0);
        String code = JO.getString("code");
        String message = JO.getString("message");

        if (code.equals("reg_true")) {

            showDialog("Registration Success", code, message);

        } else if (code.equals("reg_false")) {


            showDialog("Registration Failed", code, message);

        } else if (code.equals("login_true")) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (code.equals("login_false")) {
            showDialog("Login Error", code, message);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showDialog(String title, String code, String message) {

    builder.setTitle(title);
    if (code.equals("reg_true") || code.equals("reg_false")) {

        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                activity.finish();
            }

        });


    } else if (code.equals("login_false")) {

        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                EditText phone_no, password;
                phone_no = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
                password = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.password);
                phone_no.setText("");
                password.setText("");
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();


}



}
```

please help Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. After clicking on login/SignIn, just check if remember me `CheckBox` is checked or not, if it is checked store userName/Email and password in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).
2. In your `onCreate()` of `LoginActivity`, check whether you have any userName/Email or password stored in `SharedPreferences`, if it is there fill your `EditText` with those UserName/Email and Password.

Comment: i want this to happen when my server response back that login is true

Comment: Well do it. If the response is bad, report an error. If not, just do what @RRR told you. It's that simple

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Log_in extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String  PREFS_NAME="NAME";
    public static String PREF_USERNAME="";
    public static String PREF_PASSWORD="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        EditText txtuser=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
        EditText txtpwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_pwd);
        CheckBox ch=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_rememberme);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = pref.getString(PREF_USERNAME, null);
        String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);

        if (username != null || password != null) {
            txtuser.setText(username);
            txtpwd.setText(password);
            ch.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            ch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    public void doLogin(View view){
        EditText txtuser=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
        EditText txtpwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_pwd);
        String username = txtuser.getText().toString();
        String password = txtpwd.getText().toString();
        CheckBox ch=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_rememberme);
        String type = "login";
        if(ch.isChecked()){
            rememberMe(username,password);
        }
        else{
            clear();
        }
        BackgroundTask bt = new BackgroundTask(this);
        bt.execute(type, username, password);
    }
    public void rememberMe(String user, String password){
        getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString(PREF_USERNAME,user)
                .putString(PREF_PASSWORD,password)
                .commit();
    }
    public void clear(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =getSharedPreferences(Log_in.PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is only for Log in activity and Background task is similar to your code